# How can the css variable from be changed dynamically from `Laravel Nova`?

Tags: css, laravel, tailwind-css, laravel-nova, inertiajs

I am using [Nova Settings](https://github.com/optimistdigital/nova-settings) in which a
[Color picker](https://github.com/optimistdigital/nova-color-field) field is used.

NovaServiceProvider-

```
\OptimistDigital\NovaSettings\NovaSettings::addSettingsFields([
            Panel::make('Colors', [
                Color::make('Primary color')->slider(),
                Color::make('Secondary color')->slider(),
            ]),
        ]);
```

`$primary-color = nova_get_setting('primary_color');`

In my CSS file -

```
:root {
    --primary-color: rgb(255, 0, 0); //want the nova color setting to be used here
    --secondary-color: rgb(255, 197, 6);
  }
```

How can the Nova setting color value be called in the CSS file to change the colors dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Nova Settings](https://github.com/optimistdigital/nova-settings) in which a
[Color picker](https://github.com/optimistdigital/nova-color-field) field is used.

In app.blade.php -

```
  <style>
    <?php
    $primaryColor = nova_get_setting('primary_color');
    $secondaryColor = nova_get_setting('secondary_color');
    ?> :root {
      --primary-color: <?php echo $primaryColor ?>;
      --secondary-color: <?php echo  $secondaryColor ?>;
    }
  </style>
```

In tailwind.config.js -

```
 theme: {       
  colors: {
   'primary-color': 'var(--primary-color)',
   'secondary-color':'var(--secondary-color) ',
  },
 },
```

Answer (score 1):

*You didn't say if you need them for the frontend or for the Nova dashboard, so I'll list both procedures.*

---

**Front End**:

```
// File: master.blade.php 
// Or the name of the main blade you extend, 
// if you haven't you will need to change the code on all blades

// Step 1: Add variable settings to the "master blade"
// Pro tip: it's nice to have a global variable with this info ;)
@php
    $settings = Config::get(‘YOUR_SETTINGS’);
@endphp

/* TAGs FOR TITLE, SEO, OTHER CSS FILES, ALL YOU NEED   */

// Step 2: 
<style>

    // If you have problems and don't see any changes, 
    // you can try, even if I don't like it as an idea, the "!important"
    :root {
        --primary-color: {{$settings['COLOR_FIELD_NAME']}};
        --secondary-color: {{$settings['COLOR_FIELD_NAME']}};
    }
 </style>
<body>
/* REST OF CODE */
```

---

**Dashboard Nova**:

I think you should go for a change of theme, maybe creating(or update) it when saving a new color (you could use an [Observer](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers)). [This is the link of the official doc](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/customization/themes.html) which is certainly much more complete than I could write it here.

---

**Nice if you want to contribute**

If you feel like it, you could fork the code written in [David Griffiths](https://github.com/David-Griffiths)' [Nova-Dark-Theme](https://github.com/David-Griffiths/Nova-Dark-Theme) package. You could create a component that also accepts custom colors and shares with community :)